# Checkboxes in one line

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, css

[image]I have an Grid with 2 checkboxes. But it's display in 2 lines and I need that display in one line (Ckeckboxes + Label).
I use CSS Bootstrap. IN Checkbox, I set to display inline.

My css.

```
input[type="checkbox"] {  cursor: pointer;  display: inline;}
```

My page:

```
<div id="Div1" width="auto" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" GridLines="None"
        CssClass="table table-bordered table-striped" Width="100%">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="idTickets" HeaderText="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="User" HeaderText="User" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RequestDate" HeaderText="Request Date" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="BusinessJustification" HeaderText="Business Justification" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="AccessType" HeaderText="Group Access" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="sub_folder_path" HeaderText="Folder Path" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ServerName" HeaderText="Server Name" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Approved/Denied">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="UserValue" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("User") %>' />
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="Approved" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_ChangeCheck"
                        AutoPostBack="true" />
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" Text="Denied" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox2_ChangeCheck"
                        AutoPostBack="true" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

How I can configure this CkechBox to display in just one row? I have this problem in other 2 pages.

Attached print:
[image]

My html:

```
<tr><td>
  <input type="hidden" name="GridView1$ctl02$UserValue" id="GridView1_UserValue_0" value="MXLozadaRa">
  <input id="GridView1_CheckBox1_0" type="checkbox" name="GridView1$ctl02$CheckBox1" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'GridView1$ctl02$CheckBox1\',\'\')', 0)">
  <label for="GridView1_CheckBox1_0">Approved</label>
  <input id="GridView1_CheckBox2_0" type="checkbox" name="GridView1$ctl02$CheckBox2" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'GridView1$ctl02$CheckBox2\',\'\')', 0)">
  <label for="GridView1_CheckBox2_0">Denied</label>
</td></tr>
```

Second Div with CkeckBox.

```
<div align="center" width="auto" id="DivCheckBox">
  <input id="ckbApprovalAll" type="checkbox" name="ckbApprovalAll" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ckbApprovalAll\',\'\')', 0)">
  <label for="ckbApprovalAll">Approved All</label>
  <input id="ckbDeniedAll" type="checkbox" name="ckbDeniedAll" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ckbDeniedAll\',\'\')', 0)">
  <label for="ckbDeniedAll">Denied All</label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="btnSend" value="Send" id="btnSend" class="btn" align="center">
</div>
```

Comment: Not exactly related to your question, but I'm guessing something can't be "Approved" and "Denied" at the same time - so I would suggest you use RadioButtons instead of CheckBoxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use table. I avoid using table these days.

In this case, GridView generates a table anyway, so it doesn't matter anymore.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
  AutoGenerateColumns="false" GridLines="None" Width="100%">
    <Columns>
        ...
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Approved/Denied">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" ... /></td>
                        <td><asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" ... /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

If you want to display both text and checkbox in a single line, you can remove text from `CheckBox`, and display in `td` separately.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" ... /></td>
        <td>Approved</td>
        <td><asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" ... /></td>
        <td>Denied</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Last but not least you can render each checkbox in separate Template Field. I prefer this approach than other two.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ...>
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Approved">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" .../>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Denied">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" ... />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Ok, works! But, how I can set this without css style? This is with the table style css

Comment: You do not need any css style for the above approaches. It might be that bootstrap css is applying table styles. If so, you will need to overrides bootstrap css. If you have question regarding how to override bootstrap css, please create a separate question with screenshot.

Comment: ok, well for this question, tks for your help! I'll create a new question for this part of the css.

Answer (score 1):

There's much easier and cleaner solution.

## Adding CssClass (proper way)

All you need to do is add a CSS class to every `asp:CheckBox` you want to render inline. If you do that, ASP will *automagically* render `input`+`label` inside a parent `span` with your class. Then, for that class you need to set `white-space: nowrap;` to stop text from breaking to another line.

```css
.cb {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" Text="Approved" CssClass="cb" />
```

## Sample Code Snippet

```css
.cb {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

/*/ Style for the sake of this Code Snippet /*/
.test-sample {
  border: dotted 1px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!--
  div.test-sample is not needed! I used it in this code snippet
  to prove that CheckBox label is not breaking to another line.
-->

<p>With <code>CssClass="cb"</code>:</p>
<div class="test-sample">
  <!-- <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="CheckBox1" Text="Approved" CssClass="cb" /> -->
  <span class="cb"><input id="CheckBox1" type="checkbox" /><label for="CheckBox1">Approved</label></span>
</div>

<p>Without <code>CssClass="cb"</code>:</p>
<div class="test-sample">
  <!-- <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="CheckBox2" Text="Approved" /> -->
  <input id="CheckBox2" type="checkbox" /><label for="CheckBox2">Approved</label>
</div>
```

I don't recommend using tables for such a simple task. That's overkill and you may have issues in the future, as tables' behaviour is generally hard to predict.

Also, try to **not** render CheckBox and its label separately as some people recommended in this thread, unless you'll provide appropriate feedback and render proper `label` element. CheckBoxes without `label` element are very frustrating to use, because they're breaking users' natural habits of clicking on caption, instead of teeny–tiny little square.

*Stay simple!

~Wiktor*

Answer (score 0):

You have to set display to block. Also you have to set width and height to your last td.
For example:

```
input,span
{
float:left
display:block;
}
```

Comment: But what "span" has to do with it? I changed my checkbox config display: inline to display: block, but not work and it was with "float: left"! :S

Comment: because your td must have width. And you must put your label in span or div.

Answer (score 0):

you could also use `white-space: no wrap` check on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp)

I could reproduce your problem, your label may inheritance `display:block`. I fix it adding  a `display: inline` to it.

Check how it results

```
<div style= "white-space: nowrap;">
        <input id="ckbApprovalAll" type="checkbox" name="ckbApprovalAll" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ckbApprovalAll\',\'\')', 0)">
        <label style="display: inline" for="ckbApprovalAll">Approved All</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I updated my answer, please check and tell me if it does work

Answer (score 0):

Try CSS your div

```
.Div1 { white-space: nowrap; display:inline }
```

Answer (score 0):

You *must* set a `width` to that last column, or else the `float:left` won't work. Try with bigger `width`s first then go smaller until you find your ideal setting. Good luck!